# Is ${v_1, v_2}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $$v_1=  \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
          -2 \\
           3
  \end{bmatrix},\quad v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 &\\
     7\\
    -9
  \end{bmatrix}$$

> Will it be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not $\mathbb{R}^2$, how do I show this since i cant take it determinant?

Comment: you only have 2 vectors in your basis, so no, it can not be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: ic, then how do i check if it is a basis for R2 since there is two vectors?

Comment: It's not a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ since the vectors are not elements of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Think about how many vectors and how many components you need to represent a space. Think about what kind of matrix (whose columns can be thought of as vectors of the space) you need to even be able to take determinants.

Comment: Your two vectors can be a basis for a 2-dimensional space, but that space is not $\mathbb{R}^2$...it is a plane existing in 3 dimensions, but is nonetheless a plane...

Comment: I just have a really hard time visualizing this, so what you mean is that it's not a basis for R2 since it is within R2 (x,y-plane)?(never mine forget what I just said (its x,y,z)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 3-dimensional space requires 3 basis vectors so the $v_1, v_2$ you have listed are not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since they are linearly independent, they do form a basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is an embedded copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$.